# Image downloading instead of displaying in browser using amazon s3 - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

i'm trying to upload images to S3 Amazon, when i submit through form, it will successfully uploaded, but the url of the image when i hit, it will download the image instead of displaying image in browser, Please check my code, i'm waiting of your kind response.

```
if ($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, "bucket/images", $fileName, 
S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)) {
echo "We successfully uploaded your file.";
}else{
echo "Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.";
}

// Get the contents of our bucket
$url = "http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/images/".$fileName;
printf($url);
exit();
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/298735/amazon-s3-access-image-by-url

Comment: Daisha Thanks for reply, Dear, i got successfully url, my issue is, when i hit the url, the image automatically starting download, even i want to view image not download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i traced myself and finally i resolved this issue. Simply, we need to add [array $metaHeaders = array()], [string $contentType = null] in putObjectFile() parameters, through this image will open in browser instead download. So, now i changed code:

```
$fileName       =   $_FILES['file']['name'];
$fileTempName   =   $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$contentType    =   $_FILES['file']['type']; 
$metaHeaders = array();

if($s3->putObjectFile($file, "bucket", $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ, $metaHeaders, $contentType)){
echo "We successfully uploaded your file.";
                }
else{
                 echo "Something went wrong while uploading your file... sorry.";
                }
```

So, it's working absolutely fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Insted of `printf($url);` try this

```
echo "<a href='$url'>$url</a>";
```

Comment: Syed Suleman thanks for reply, i changed code according to your comment, but it still download image instead view image.

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code for my bucket. Try if it works for you.

```
<?php $client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'region' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    ));

function getDocFromS3($file, $doc_type){
    global $client;

    $bucket_dir = getBucketName($doc_type);
    /*$result = $client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket_dir,
            'Key'    => $file
    ));*/
    $file = "{$bucket_dir}/{$file}";
    $result = $client->get($file);
    $url = $result->getURL();

    return $url;

}

function getBucketName($doc_type){
    if(DEV || LCD){
        $bucket_name = 'public-estify-dev';
    } else {
        $bucket_name = 'public-estify';
    }

    return $bucket_name.'/evm/docs/'.$doc_type;
} ?>
```

Comment: Disha, i tried your code but it's showing this error: <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>images/testingimg10.png</Key>

Comment: Well, you need to add your credentials in $client array

Comment: Yes i tried with added these credential; First i tried: $client = \Aws\S3\S3Client::factory(array(
                    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                    'secret' => ''XXXXXXXXXXX'
                    //'region' => 'XXXXXXXX',
                )); 
then it’s showing this error: Fatal error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found in
then I tired this 
$client = new S3('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');        

then this will comes

<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>images/testingimg10.png</Key

Comment: Credentials must be wrong to throw "Key does not exist" error

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, But Disha when i tried my code which i added in my question, it's work fine and uploaded image to s3 and when i hit url then it will download the image even credentials are same :-(

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping, Disha we need to add [array $metaHeaders = array()], [string $contentType = null] in putObjectFile() parameters. then its working.

Comment: Glad, you helped yourself :)

Comment: hahaha. Can you give me vote on my post, then it will comes on top for helping other guys who will face same problem. Thanks